# Change class on span inside button as sender

Tags: html, css, asp.net, linkbutton, asplinkbutton

I wonder if its possible to select the  inside a specific LinkButton in code behind.

That I want to make is when the button is clicked the span inside the button should change class. I know i can change it if i set an ID on the span but i wonder if its possible to get the span by the button as sender.

The button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnAttestMonday" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success  btn-xs" OnClick="btnAttest_Click" CausesValidation="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" runat="server"></span></asp:LinkButton>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void btnChangeAttest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;

    switch (btn.CommandName)
    {
        case "Attest":
            updateAttestInDB(btn.CommandArgument.ToString(), true);
            btn.CommandName = "RemoveAttest";
            break;
        case "RemoveAttest":
            updateAttestInDB(btn.CommandArgument.ToString(), false);
            btn.CommandName = "Attest";
            break;
    }      
}
```

I want the span to change class inside the switch cases.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"to select the inside a specific LinkButton"_? Make the span a  `Label` and you're done.

Comment: But i need to use the component from bootstrap. I think its only span who works in that scenario right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the span a `Label` and you're done. Then you just need to access it via `ID`.  However, if you don't want that you can access it via the `LinkButton`'s 
[`Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx)-collection:

```
protected void btnAttest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
    var span = (HtmlGenericControl) btn.Controls[0];
    span.Attributes["class"] = "newCssClass";
    // ...
}
```

Of course that fails at runtime if you will change the layout in future.